# What's a word that encompasses both transmit and receive?

Tags: terminology, soft-question, antennas

Is there a word that can be used to describe in a general sense the action of an antenna, whether transmitting or receiving?

My best guess is "couple" as in coupling energy from a wire to EM wave, or vice versa. However I feel like this isn't completely clear.

Comment: What about [*transceiver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transceiver)?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking more about the _action_ of transmitting or receiving, rather than a device that can either transmit or receive, which would of course be an antenna. :)

Comment: If it's the Physics, rather than the technological application, that you're thinking about, then "couple" is just the word you want. The aerial (sorry, antenna) couples the macroscopic oscillations of electrons to an e-m wave, whether you're transmitting or receiving.

Comment: What about communicate?

Answer (score 2):

Transceive. Verb. To both transmit and recieve

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/transceive